# Identify Access Records with Alpha Character in String

Tags: ms-access-2010

I need to identify records with a FacilityTypeID starting with an alphabetical letter in a string as these are the only records that I want to use in my results. Example:

| ContractID | FacilityTypeID |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 72 |
| 2345 | 71 |
| 3456 | A0 |
| 4567 | H0 |
| 5678 | G1 |

I want to only pull A0, H0 and G1 into my final results.

Comment: `WHERE FacilityTypeID LIKE  "[A-Z]*"` -- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-query-criteria-3197228c-8684-4552-ac03-aba746fb29d8

Comment: Thank you!! I had tried something similar but did not have it quite right.